# retrieve characters after a dash at the end of url

Tags: jquery

I would like to retrieve the last word that appears after the dash in this url:

http://domain.com.store/Sites-DE-Site/de_DE/mccDefault-Start#!%2FproductList%3Fcgid%3DprivateSale13-women

I retrieve the url as follows:

```
$(location).attr('href');
//pure javascript
var pathName = window.location.pathname;
```

but then I'd like to extract the word that appears after the (-) dash at the end, so in the case above "women".

How could I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `var hreff = pathName.split("-"); var ah_word = hreff[1]`

Comment: `window.location.pathname.substring(window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf("-")+1)`

Comment: `var dashed = pathName.split("-").pop()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array prototype `.pop()` method to retrieve last item of an array:

```
var dashed = pathName.split("-").pop();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/atfF4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
url_string      = document.location.href;
url_array       = url_string.split('-');
after_last_dash = url_array[url_array.length-1];
alert( after_last_dash );
```